# Bash script to download graphic files from website

Tags: linux, bash, curl, graphics, download

I'm trying to write bash script in Linux (Debian), that will be used for downloading graphic files from website given by user during start-up. I'm not sure if my code is correct but first problem is when i try to run my script with website e.g. `http://www.bbc.com/` an error shows: `http://www.bbc.com/  : invalid identifier`. I even tried a simple website that has only a few JPG files. My next problem is to find out how to download files from .txt file where the images Internet adresses are included.

```
#!/bin/bash
# $1 - URL        $2 - new catalog name
read $1 $2
url=$1
fold=$2
mkdir -p $fold

if [$# -ne 3];
then
echo "Wrong command"
exit -1
fi

curl $url | grep -o -e "<img src=\".*\"+>" > img_list.txt |wc -l img_list.txt |  lin=${% *}

baseurl=$(echo $url | grep -o "https?://[a-z.]*"")
curl -s $url | egrep -o "<img src\=[^>]*>" | sed 's/<img src=\"\([^"]*\).*/\1/.*/\1/g' >  url_list.txt

sed -i "s|^/|$baseurl/|" url_list.txt
cd $fold;
```

what can I do next?

Comment: did you try another link?

Comment: yes, I did, even a simple website that has only a few JPG files.

Answer (score 0):

For download every image from the webpage I would to use:

```
mech-dump --absolute --images http://example.com | xargs -n1 curl -O
```

but this need to be installed the [mech-dump](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/WWW-Mechanize/bin/mech-dump) command from the `WWW::Mechanize` package.

Using the list file

```
while read -r url folder
do
    mkdir -p "$folder" || exit 1
    (cd "$folder" && mech-dump --absolute --images "$url" | xargs -n1 curl -O)
done < list.txt
```

(assuming than no url nor folder containing a space).

Answer (score 0):

> an error shows: `http://www.bbc.com/  : invalid identifier`

Your use of `read` is wrong; change

```
read $1 $2
url=$1
fold=$2
```

to

```
read url fold
```

or decide to specify the arguments on the command line and omit only `read $1 $2`.

Also, each operand in `[` `]` must be separated from the brackets; change

```
if [$# -ne 3];
```

to

```
if [ -z "$fold" ]
```